# jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format - Datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, format

I want to format my date in `dd/mm/yy`.
This is my code, it doesn't work:

```
var lStartDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();

 alert(lStartDate)
```

Now I receive alert with `"06/29/2017"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [two-digit year on datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989591/two-digit-year-on-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Comment: this will not help the OP with his problem

Comment: No, jQuery UI's datepicker has this as default and the `yy` is read as a 4-digit year. It needs a single `y` for 2-digit year.

Comment: i believe two digit is not he is concerned about.The data format he is getting is incorrect.He is expecting day/month/year but getting month/day/year

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the right solution:

```
var lStartDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=text  data-date-format='dd/mm/yy' class="form-control" required>
```

Try this